# Insert missing date records in the multi level time series data

Tags: mysql

**Background**
The data I have is fairly straight forward. Multiple Clients, each client can have multiple accounts and each account can contain multiple products (cusips). I capture this data on every work day which means there are no records for the weekends or any public holiday.

```
 Client    Account   Product        Total_value     Date
 10        36        '29764T101'    3240            '2018-10-01' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       29761.93        '2018-10-02' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3720            '2018-10-02' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       29761.93        '2018-10-03' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3240            '2018-10-03' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-04' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-04' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-05' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-05' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-08' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-08' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-09' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3060            '2018-10-09'
```

**Problem Statement**
I need a way to insert records for the missing days in the monthly time series data. The missing data is derived from the last available data row. So a friday record would get repeated for the saturday and sunday. If wednesday was non-working, tuesday's record will get populated for wednesday and so on.

In the above data, there is no data for Oct 6th and Oct 7th. Since this client (10) have two accounts (35, 36) and each account has only one product (35->'TRZ300' and 36->'29764T101'), I need a way to insert two records for 6th (copy of the two records on 5th) and the same thing to be repeated for 6th.

Note that my data is at Client/Account/product/date level and this combo needs to be looked up and replicated. The sample data above is for only one client. The actual data has multiple clients, with multiple accounts and each accounts can have multiple products(cusips).

**Expected Output**

```
 Client    Account   Product        Total_value     Date
 10        36        '29764T101'    3240            '2018-10-01' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       29761.93        '2018-10-02' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3720            '2018-10-02' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       29761.93        '2018-10-03' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3240            '2018-10-03' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-04' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-04' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-05' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-05'

 ------------------------ Inserted Records --------------------- 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-06' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-06' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-07' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-07' 
 ------------------------ Inserted Records ---------------------

 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-08' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3300            '2018-10-08' 
 10        35        'TRZ300'       30282.76        '2018-10-09' 
 10        36        '29764T101'    3060            '2018-10-09'
```

**Tried so far**
I understand that one approach might be to create a calendar table and then do a left join.

**Attempt 1**
I got the solution working by creating a calendar table and then using the following query:

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1)  
ELSE ID END ID,
CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN (SELECT Name 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1) 
ELSE Name END Name,
CASE WHEN SomeVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT SomeVal 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1) 
ELSE SomeVal END SomeVal,
CASE WHEN OtherVal IS NULL THEN (SELECT OtherVal 
                        FROM T tt 
                        WHERE tt.Date < t1.minDt
                        ORDER BY tt.Date DESC
                        LIMIT 1) 
ELSE OtherVal END OtherVal,
minDt
FROM calendar t1 
LEFT JOIN T t2 ON t1.minDt = t2.Date
ORDER BY t1.minDT;
```

This solution worked when the ID value was constant. I realized that my dataset has thousands of records with few hundred unique id values. Each id can have missing values. The above query replaces just top of the data, not the entire data. I need to run the same query for each id. I guess partition by works in mysql but I am not quite sure how to try it.

**Attempt 2**
This is a recommendation by @Nick. I don't follow it entirely but it worked on my dummy data which was however at only one level. I am not too sure about how to extend this solution to a multi level data, like what I have above.

```
SELECT thedate,
       @name := coalesce(Name, @name) AS Name,
       @someval := coalesce(SomeVal, @someval) AS SomeVal,
       @otherval := coalesce(OtherVal, @otherval) AS OtherVal,
       @id := id AS id
FROM (SELECT c.thedate, i.id, t.Name, t.SomeVal, t.OtherVal
      FROM calendar c
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t) i
      LEFT JOIN t ON t.date = c.thedate AND t.id = i.id) g
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0, @name := '', @someval := 0, @otherval := 0) v
ORDER BY id, thedate
```

**DB-Fiddle Sample Data**
I've already created a dummy data, for anyone to fiddle with at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wzg4mYtbdTeJGrGHfqJ75k/1

Both the sample data and calendar data.